# how to set connection timeout in tornado?

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, tornado, ping

In my Tornado app in some situation some clients disconnect from server but my current code doesn't detect that client is disconnect from server. I currently use ping to find out if client is disconnected.
here is my ping pong code:

```
from threading import Timer
class SocketHandler(websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def __init__(self, application, request, **kwargs):
        # some code here
        Timer(5.0, self.do_ping).start()
    def do_ping(self):
        try:
            self.ping_counter += 1
            self.ping("")
            if self.ping_counter > 2:
                self.close()
            Timer(60, self.do_ping).start()
        except WebSocketClosedError:
            pass

    def on_pong(self, data):
        self.ping_counter = 0
```

now I want to set SO_RCVTIMEO in tornado instead of using ping pong method.
something like this :
`sock.setsockopt(socket.SO_RCVTIMEO)`
Is it possible to set SO_RCVTIMEO in Tornado for close clients from server after specific time out ?

Comment: @amn how can I use `socket.SO_RCVTIMEO` in Tornado ? I read the docs but can't find something useful.

Answer (score 1):

`SO_RCVTIMEO` does not do anything in an asynchronous framework like Tornado. You probably want to wrap your reads in `tornado.gen.with_timeout`. You'll still need to use pings to test the connection and make sure it is still working; if the connection is idle there are few guarantees about how long it will take for the system to notice. (TCP keepalives are a possibility, but these are not configurable on all platforms and generally use very long timeouts).

Comment: thanks. then with tornado we can't detect or refresh idle connections ? even with `with_timeout` generator ?

Comment: You need to use a connection periodically to be able to detect failures on it. This is true of TCP in general, not just Tornado (you'd need something to read for `SO_RCVTIMEO` to work in a synchronous app). The only way to detect failures without attempting to use the connection is with TCP keepalives, with the aforementioned limitations.

Comment: Also note that WebSocketHandler now has built in ping and timeout support in Tornado 4.5, so for websockets you should use that instead of building your own failure detector.